# Ubuntu 18.04 keyboard and mouse clicks freeze

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 on a new laptop - Lenovo T580

Every now and then the keyboard freezes. Also the mouse doesn't fully work. I can move the mouse but not click anything except the side panel on the left and the toolbar icons across the top.

I can left click and right click on the side panel - so I can quit the applications but I can't click or tab to the save buttons which is becoming annoying. I can also click the power button in the toolbar to restart too.

It's only fixed if I do a restart. If I try to log out and back in, the keyboard and mouse is still locked. If I switch accounts, then the keyboard works okay.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode?

Comment: It is. I entered `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Installed in UEFI mode" || echo "Installed in Legacy mode"` which displayed `Installed in UEFI mode` - from [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_an_Ubuntu_has_been_installed_in_UEFI_mode]

Comment: Does it have a discreet graphics card?

Comment: How do I find that?

Comment: You should know what hardware you have?!? Forget the qualified, I'm just asking whether you have Intel, Nvidia or AMD (or a combination of Intel with another in which case does it happen when running with one or it happens regardless of the profile).

Comment: I meant how do I check if I am using a discrete graphics card? I know what hardware I have, its an NVIDIA GeForce MX150 GDDR5 2G

Comment: That's what matters. First of all, please [edit] the question and add that information along with the Nvidia drivers you installed. If you didn't then that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: It's a bit arrogant to assume the user knows and understands what hardware he/she/* has. I'm having the same issues as this user. I use Ubuntu because I prefer it over Windows. I'm not a tech geek. Settings tells me I have an AMD Fx-8320 8-core processor and AMD Pitcarin grahics. I have also noticed that usually *but not always* when a freeze occurs that `top` indicates some application is using >100% CPU.